# window.plugins undefined in cordova-2.0.0

Tags: cordova, barcode-scanner, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-webworks

I'm trying to use the BarcodeScanner plugin for Cordova in a BlackBerry device without luck. The sample code makes use of this structure:

```
window.plugins.BarcodeScanner...
```

but `window.plugins` is `undefined`.

I tried with a fresh new application and `window.plugins` continues to be `undefined` (I mean, the sample application without any addition).

Did the api have changed and the documentation is outdated or there's something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that currently the syntax is quite different: http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/_barcodescanner_plugin_upgrading_scanner_javascript_api_code_changes_required

Comment: "This question is unlikely to help any future visitors;" How come it has 9 votes and 7689 views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All, I pushed a new BarcodeScanner this morning that works with 2.0.0.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner/2.0.0

Comment: Thanks! There's any idea when it will be available for BlackBerry?

Comment: It is now available for BB https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/BlackBerry/BarcodeScanner

Comment: It sais the last change was 2 month ago. Maybe there's a pending pull request.

Comment: Sorry I was on vacation. It says the last change was 13 days ago for me and that is just before I took off.

Answer (score 8):

Cordova 2.0 has removed the "addPlugin" method used by the BarcodeScanner plugin. So a quick fix would be to remove (or comment out) the "addConstructor" function used to add the plugin, and replace it with an explicit attachment to the window object:

```
//cordova.addConstructor(function() {
//    cordova.addPlugin('barcodeScanner', new BarcodeScanner());
//});

window.barcodeScanner = new BarcodeScanner();
```

Then, since "window.plugins" isn't used, you will also need to change the code that calls the "scan" method, so replace

```
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(...
```

with

```
window.barcodeScanner.scan(...
```

I have tested this with Cordova 2.0 and it works.

Comment: but when ever i am calling **window.barcodeScanner.scan(...** some times it calls to my plugin and some times not.......can u tell me why? and gives me **window.barcodeScanner.scan[undefined]is not a function**

Comment: A sample of your code would be needed to help diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into the same problem. After looking into the window-object I found the BarcodeScanner being right there.
So`window.BarcodeScanner.prototype.scan(result, error)` did the trick.
Make sure you wait for cordova to be fully initialized, otherwise you may get sth like `has no method exec()`

Comment: you mean, just call `window.BarcodeScanner`?

Comment: yep, that's what worked for me. if you `console.log(window)` you should see the `BarcodeScanner`

Comment: Didn't work. `window.BarcodeScanner` is `undefined` too.

Comment: without modifying anything in the plugin itself: 
`var bcs = new window.BarcodeScanner(); console.log(bcs)` 

**returns** 

`BarcodeScanner
       __proto__: Object
       constructor: function () {
       encode: function (type, data, successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
       scan: function (successCallback, errorCallback) {
       __proto__: Object`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used cordova 1.9.0, as plugins are not up-to-date yet.

Thanks to everyone!