# Cordova/phonegap (2.7!) save canvas as binary file

Tags: android, cordova

I'm working on an app that let's you doodle (draw) on a screenshot (or any other picture on your phone) and then save it. It's built in cordova/phonegap and thus far everything works just fine.. I just don't know how to save the image to the device's storage.

Short: I need to save the imagedata of a canvas to storage.

I tried a plugin but it isn't working (written for an older version of cordova/phonegap?) and whatever I tried, I couldn't fix it.

Any ideas?

(Im using cordova 2.7)

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt the plugin I was using (base64ToPNG, link below) following the guide on the Cordova 2.7 documentation (Plugin development guide) but still couldn't get it working; javascript said window.plugins was undefined.

Turns out that this has changed in some Cordova version. What I find weird is that another plugin I have used in an earlier project did exactly the same thing and that worked. Weird.

Anyway, I followed the steps as described here: [window.plugins undefined in cordova-2.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613274/window-plugins-undefined-in-cordova-2-0-0)

and it looks like everything works fine now.

Original plugin (for cordova < 1.6)
[Phonegap Plugin:How to convert Base64 String to a PNG image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388018/phonegap-plugin-to-convert-base64-string-to-a-png-image-in-android)